# Is there a way to read a GStreamer rtp stream with FFMPEG/FFPLAY?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, gstreamer, h.264, rtp

I have an RTP stream generated by GStreamer using the following code and It can't be touched because It's a simulation of an RTP stream generated by a drone:

```
gst-launch-1.0.exe filesrc location=./Bomb_Detection_long.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! h264parse ! queue ! rtph264pay config-interval=10 pt=96 ! udpsink host=localhost port=5600
```

I need to read the stream using FFMPEG/FFPLAY, so I checked if it is possible with the following ffplay code:

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -vcodec h264 -pixel_format yuv420p -framerate 30 -video_size 1280x720 rtp://localhost:5600
```

[All of my tests gets this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbgE4.jpg).

I also tried to set all the others h264 video decoders available (h264_qsv, libopenh264, h264_cuvid) with no success.

If it can be helpful, I am able to read the stream using the following GStreamer command (but again: I need to read it using FFMPEG/FFPLAY instead):

```
udpsrc port=5600 ! application/x-rtp, payload=96 ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! decodebin ! videoflip method=rotate-180 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=(string)BGR ! videoconvert ! appsink emit-signals=true sync=false max-buffers=2 drop=true
```

Here is the ffprobe:

```
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\Bomb_Detection_long.mp4':
Duration: 00:04:44.20, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4421 kb/s
Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Video: h264 (Constrained Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1280x720, 4222 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 15360 tbn (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : VideoHandler
    vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 191 kb/s (default)
  Metadata:
    handler_name    : SoundHandler
    vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
```

Is there a way to read the GStreamer stream using FFMPEG/FFPLAY?

Answer (score 0):

ffplay -protocol_whitelist file,rtp,udp -i test.sdp

You need to write the test.sdp file yourself though

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).